# Format Time in Kendo

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo Grid to submit Time(12 hour format) value to database

```
 columns.Bound(o => o.From).Title("From").Format("{0:hh:mm tt}").EditorTemplateName("Time");
```

It saves the time in the format below and it displays the time in the grid in the same format. How can I show only the time value in the grid?

```
Mon Jun 30 2014 00:30:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is use the data annotation attribute on your property in your model.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}")]
public DateTime From {get; set;}
```

Then when creating your grid:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.From).Title("From")
```

This will display the time only.

See the MSDN formats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more format options

Hope that helps